# Proper way to handle nullable fields in RavenDB Map/Reduces?

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, ravendb, nullable, reduce

How should I Map an object with a nullable field? I guess I must turn the nullable field into a non-nullable version, and it's that step that I stumble upon.

What is the proper way to map nullable properties?

```
public class Visit {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int? MediaSourceId { get; set; }
}

public class MapReduceResult
{
    public string VisitId { get; set; }
    public int MediaSourceId { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

AddMap<Visit>(
    visits =>
    from visit in visits
    select new
        {
            VisitId = visit.Id,
            MediaSourceId =
                (visit.MediaSourceId.HasValue)
                ? visit.MediaSourceId
                : UNUSED_MEDIASOURCE_ID,
            Version = (string) null,
            Count = 1
        });
```

This doesn't work! In fact; this Map is completely ignored, while the other Maps work fine, and they are in the end Reduced as expected.

Thanks for helping me!

Below is a newly added test case that fails with a "Cannot assign <null> to anonymous type property". How am I supposed to get this flying with the least amount of pain?

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyIndexTest
{
    private IDocumentStore _documentStore;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {RunInMemory = true}.Initialize();
        _documentStore.DatabaseCommands.DisableAllCaching();

        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof (MyIndex).Assembly, _documentStore);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _documentStore.Dispose();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldWork()
    {
        InitData();

        IList<MyIndex.MapReduceResult> mapReduceResults = null;
        using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            mapReduceResults =
                session.Query<MyIndex.MapReduceResult>(
                    MyIndex.INDEX_NAME)
                    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()).ToArray();
        }
        Assert.That(mapReduceResults.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    private void InitData()
    {
        var visitOne = new Visit
                           {
                               Id = "visits/64",
                               MetaData = new MetaData {CreatedDate = new DateTime(1975, 8, 6, 0, 14, 0)},
                               MediaSourceId = 1,
                           };
        var visitPageVersionOne = new VisitPageVersion
                                      {
                                          Id = "VisitPageVersions/123",
                                          MetaData = new MetaData {CreatedDate = new DateTime(1975, 8, 6, 0, 14, 0)},
                                          VisitId = "visits/64",
                                          Version = "1"
                                      };

        using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(visitOne);
            session.Store(visitPageVersionOne);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public class MyIndex :
        AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask
            <MyIndex.MapReduceResult>
    {
        public const string INDEX_NAME = "MyIndex";

        public override string IndexName
        {
            get { return INDEX_NAME; }
        }

        public class MapReduceResult
        {
            public string VisitId { get; set; }
            public int? MediaSourceId { get; set; }
            public string Version { get; set; }
            public int Count { get; set; }
        }

        public MyIndex()
        {
            AddMap<Visit>(
                visits =>
                from visit in visits
                select new
                           {
                               VisitId = visit.Id,
                               MediaSourceId = (int?) visit.MediaSourceId,
                               Version = (string) null,
                               Count = 1
                           });
            AddMap<VisitPageVersion>(
                visitPageVersions =>
                from visitPageVersion in visitPageVersions
                select new
                           {
                               VisitId = visitPageVersion.VisitId,
                               MediaSourceId = (int?) null,
                               Version = visitPageVersion.Version,
                               Count = 0
                           });
            Reduce =
                results =>
                from result in results
                group result by result.VisitId
                into g
                select
                    new
                        {
                            VisitId = g.Key,
                            MediaSourceId = (int?) g.Select(x => x.MediaSourceId).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Version = g.Select(x => x.Version).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                        };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to give nullables special treatment.
RavenDB will already take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I added a full test case that shows my problem. It ends with throwing a "Cannot assign <null>...". What is the preferred way of handling this when Raving?

Comment: @Oren, how does RavenDB handle the "NULL part" in reduce (e.g. Version = g.Select(x => x.Version).FirstOrDefault()). Also I found out that using only First() would produce 0 results. I had to use FirstOrDefault(). I think this is what you meant by "You don't need to do anything to give nullables special treatment. RavenDB will already take care of that". Would love to understand how it's been done.